# Outlook 2013 - Automatically Delete Emails (no Auto-Archive)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Our Messaging group has disabled Auto-Archive via Group Policy for "reasons." Is there a way to automatically delete emails after a given time?

I receive hundreds of system-generated emails a day that I only want to keep around for a week, for reference purposes in case there's an issue. The only way I know to automatically delete emails after a time is Auto-Archive, so I'm hoping that there's another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple suggestions:

- Manual: Use Outlook's quick search and search for items received before DD/MM/YYYY, highlight them all (Ctrl+A), and delete them (Del).
- Automated: Write a VBA macro to do it for you each time you open Outlook.

Info regarding that suggestion to get you started:

- [VBA to delete Outlook messages from a user created folder over certain time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916078/vba-to-delete-outlook-messages-from-a-user-created-folder-over-certain-time-peri)
- [Is it possible to run a VBA function whenever Outlook starts up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565231/is-it-possible-to-run-a-vba-function-whenever-outlook-starts-up)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The automated way to set a retention policy on the folder level.

- Right-click the folder that contains your system generated e-mails.
- Select Properties
- Go to Policy tab
- In Folder Policy dropdown, select 1 Week Delete

[image: Folder Policy]

Comment: The Policy tab does not exist for me. I'm guessing that it is also disabled or is not present on 2013.

Comment: I'm going to guess your instance of Outlook has a group policy to restrict that as well.